# IntelliJ IDEA does not detect classpath library jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, jar

I am attempting to add an external jar to my module's classpath.  I've followed the directions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project?rq=1) and the compiler is still unable to find the jar.  I'm using intelliJ 14.1. I have verified that the jar is intact and not corrupt.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which compiler is unable to find the jar? Are you using IntelliJ IDEA's internal build system, or running your Ant build script? Adding a library to an IntelliJ IDEA project will not affect the behavior of your Ant script; it's completely independent.

Comment: When I go to 'Java Compiler' in the preferences, it just says Javac, so it's probably not using Ant.  I don't intend to use Ant, I'm just new to IntelliJ and wasn't sure yet how it was building behind the scenes.

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of your module configuration in IntelliJ IDEA (from the Project Structure dialog).

Comment: screenshot attached...

Comment: The library is configured correctly. Please check the settings of your module and make sure that the library is referenced in the "Dependencies" tab.

Comment: k. added second screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Well this was an easy one.  The jar file was corrupt. Problem solved.